# How to get print option in every column for particular data in certain design in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, html

In every column there should be a print option. When a particular option is clicked, it will be printed in a certain design or format, but not all the data at a time in PHP MySQL. If anyone knows how to do this, please help me.

Comment: what you have trying exactly? put some code here..

Comment: mysql_select_db("billing",$db);
 $val=$_GET["From"];
 $val1=$_GET["To"];
 $sql="select * from billing.order where receipt_date='$val'";
 $sql = "SELECT * from billing.order WHERE receipt_date BETWEEN '$val' AND '$val1'"; <input type="button" value="Print this page" onClick="window.print()"> iam using this code for printing complete window after searching but i want only specific selected data to print ex: if only i selected id it has to be print and it should be displayed in new window

Answer (score 0):

As per I understand , you want print button or a link for print. So use this two method

```
<input type="button" onClick="javascript_print_function">Print

<a href="javascript_print_function">Print</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to have the "print" button invoke a new window which contains just the single row of data, then print that. Maybe that can call print() onload.

Trying to have all the print buttons on one page, and have it select a one from a selection of special print.css file is probably possible, but I have never seen this being done, and sounds as if it could get messy if you have a variety of pages to cater for.

Google `multiple print css files` suggests some ways of doing this, but I suspect it would be easier to pull off using divs instead of tables.